# copy Datarow to new Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

Hy there.
I have a problem when copying a row from a datatable to another one.
I know the question was make from a lot of people and there's a lot of solution, but i didn't found any that work for me

I just tried a lot of proposed solution but the error is always the same, when i try to access a specific property:

The 'Type' column does not belong to the `<tableName>` table.

here a snippet of last solution tried:

```
Dim dtTemp As DataTable = dtOriginal.Clone
Dim drTemp As DataRow = dtTemp.NewRow()
drTemp.ItemArray = row.ItemArray()
dtTemp.Rows.Add(drTemp)
```

another solution tried is:

```
Dim dtTemp As DataTable = dtOriginal.Clone  
dtTemp.ImportRow(row)    'row is the a row take from the dtOriginal.Rows with a For Each statement
```

I Pass the new Datatable to a function and had error when i'm trying to access a property(column)

```
Public Function fetchDatatable(ByVal dt As DataTable)
   ...
   For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
      If row("Type").ToString.Trim = "S" Then
```

I'm really out of ideas to how solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first two snippets are the same as `dim dtTemp = dt.Clone() dtTemp.Rows.Add(dt.Rows(0).ItemArray)`, which has no reason to fail, since both DataTables have the same schema. -- It's not clear what the third snippet has to do with the others. + Post the error you received and a single piece of code that describes the actual procedure (as a whole). -- As a note, never assign names to Columns that might represent a Type or a reserved keyword. Add a prefix to the Fields' names or whatever other pattern you see fit.

Comment: thanks @Jimi . The third snippet is the part that represent the way i try to read the property and is where the error occour. I'll suppose the same thing about the name of the property that might represent a Type or a reserved keyword, tried change the name from 'Type' in 'DeliveryType', but nothings changed. I can't post the single procedura, it will be too much long with a lot of insignificant parts in relations to the problem, but if you think it can help i'll post it

Comment: So, this is not the real code, it's something that is supposed to replicate the problem, but of course it doesn't. As mentioned, it's not clear at all how the third snippet of code is related to the others -- Post the error you receive while loping the Rows and of course check whether the cloned DataTable is actually trying to add Rows from the source DataTable (and not another). -- Without a meaningful sample of the original code, it's difficult to say what the problem is.

Comment: A snippet, by definition, is a part of a larger and more complex whole. So yes, it is the real code, cut of all that is useless to the understanding of the single problem. I thought it inappropriate to post hundreds of lines of code and it seemed to me that the information presented was clear enough, next time I'll be more precise. However, I believe I came across the error, which resided in the stored procedure I was calling to retrieve the data. Some columns that were extracted had been commented and then, obviously, they were not found. I apologize for the inconvenience